# Is it ok if I use this <title> tag?

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, seo, wp-blog-header.php

I'm using

```
<title><?php echo get_bloginfo('title'); ?></title>
```

but it shows the same title in all pages. Is it any way to show the title post, the separator and the blog name in the  tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress generates TITLE tag on its own, and you should not add title tag like that into the theme. Here is the article on WordPress Codex on how to add title tag support to the theme: [Title Tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag).

By default, WordPress includes website name in the title tag too, and if you implement it like this, SEO plugins will be able to modify the title tag.

Comment: Is there any way to capitilize them?

Comment: Capitalize what exactly? The whole title in all upper case, or only some letters? It is not recommended SEO practice to make title all upper case, it might look 'spammy' to users seeing that in search results. I remember reading a while back that search engines don't have special provisions about that, but all uppercase title will take more space and will be not be displayed in full in search results (Google limits the length of search results).

Comment: I was thinking about capitilizing the title, but now with your explanations I won't... I thought it would be worth. Thanks for your help, Milan!

Comment: Best way to handle titles is by using some SEO plugin that allows you to customize elements order and other things. It is important that theme has properly implemented tag support, and SEO plugins take care of the rest.

Comment: I use Yoast plugin to do that, but I didn't see any changes after I installed the plugin but I realized it was for the title tag I had in the header.php of my theme. Now I see the titles as I set up in Yoast. I realized, I have the menu items in my theme displayed in uppercase with css and in the "pages" page, the name of the page was written in capital letters that why the titles were displayed in capital letters...